# Which song is played in One Piece Episode 395 when Zoro loses his way?

Tags: one-piece, music

Which theme song is played in starting of this [Zoro's haki](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdmWooMrx-s) video?

Answer (score 3):

The soundtrack you are looking for is called [Three Towers.](http://youtu.be/vas_vlDjkMk)